# How do I tell OS X to always mirror displays when I plug them in?

Tags: macos, display, preferences, hdmi

I plug the same external HDMI monitor in every day, and each time, I have to manually switch from external to mirrored mode. It's minor, but annoying.

Is there a way to tell OS X to default to mirror mode whenever I plug in a monitor? I looked in `System Preferences -> Displays`, but I couldn't find such an option.

Comment: Do you use both the screens together?, if not when connecting to the external display, plug the Macbook to power and close the lid. that's what I do when I am not using the Macbook screen.

Comment: Why not just use extended mode? You benefit from the extra screen space, and the resolution would be more appropriate for each monitor

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX I did not ask for whether X was a good idea, I asked for how to do X.

Comment: I'm aware but it's a valid question nonetheless. You don't have to solve a problem that might not exist.

Comment: It's not a problem so much as a preference.

Comment: +1 because I'd like to do the opposite - always connect in extended mode since I don't want people to see my desktop when I plug in an external monitor (i.e. before I have had time to switch off mirroring). Note that a keyboard shortcut to switch between mirror and extend is Command+F1.

Comment: Man it's one of Mac stupidities. My monitor often doesn't turn on because mac is stucked on this popup and monitor is just not getting any input at all. So I have to open the lid, it is so annoying. Did you find any solution?

Comment: OMG, after 10 years and it is still exist and really it's a big issue. at least for me!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what version of OS X you are using. Yosemite remembers your settings by default so just set it once.